# Java Regex not recognizing the string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find if a string fits the format `"name"/"version"`.  Here is an example of what I expect to have.

`VideoPart/1.2`

I've tried many regexes.  The closest I have come is this:

`"[a-z,A-Z,0-9,\\.]*/[a-z,A-Z,0-9,\\.]"`

but it doesn't recognize the format.  I am being specific in this regex because I don't want anything more than just one forward-slash.  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using commas ?

Comment: Second part (after /) miss `*`.

Comment: I am under the impression that commas are like `or`'s.  The text can be any combination of those.

Comment: @falsetru, yes idk how I missed that...  Thanks!

Comment: `[a-z,A-Z,0-9,\\.]` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9,.]`. You don't have to escape periods inside character classes.

Comment: @StephenD Elements inside the character class are grouped together already, so `[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*` is the same thing. Also you may want to use `+` instead of `*` otherwise you could match single forward-slashes

Comment: @StephenD So after all these comments, you should have `[a-zA-Z0-9,.]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9,.]*` as your regex.  Is there anything else that you need?

Comment: No, this works, and you guys are extremely helpful.  Now I can tighten up all of my regexes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`\\b[a-zA-Z0-9.]+[/][a-zA-Z0-9.]+\\b`